# SP.MoveCopyUtil unavailable for use (SPO JSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, spfx-webparts

I am trying to use JSOM to programatically move existing files in a document library to a document set within the same library. I think I should be able to use SP.MoveCopyUtil.MoveFile for this purpose. The issue is that MoveCopyUtil does not show up in intellisense. When I manually type it in, I get an error: Property 'MoveCopyUtil' does not exist on type 'typeof SP'.

In config.json, I have the following entries:

```
...
    "sp-runtime": {
      "path": "https://ca03.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "microsoft-ajax"
      ]
    },
    "sharepoint": {
      "path": "https://ca03.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "sp-runtime"
      ]
    },
    "sharepoint-doc-mgmt": {
      "path": "https://ca03.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.DocumentManagement.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "sharepoint"
      ]
    }
...
```

And in the webpart itself the following statements are in place:

```
require('sp-init');
require('microsoft-ajax');
require('sp-runtime');
require('sharepoint');
```

In fact, I'm using SP.js and SP.DocumentManagement.js already to create document sets. So I don't know why the MoveCopyUtil is unavailable.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Beneath import , define

```
declare var SP:any;
```

Load libraries:

```
public render(): void {
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css');  

    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
      globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.init.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })        
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    });
```

[image]